# An answer of mine disappeared from my Stack Overflow profile

Tags: support, answers

I answered a question (which was also indicated in my Stack Overflow profile). Now, [that answer has disappeared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67330621/6451573) (moderator note: link to answer was added by a moderator, obviously OP doesn't have the link handy).

What might have happened? Since I am still quite new to Stack Overflow I would like to get the opportunity to see if my answers are helpful, etc. If they disappear from my profile I cannot track them.

Comment: You can find it if you go to your profile → Activity → Answers (the tab) next to "Summary". Go to the bottom and click on "recently deleted answers". It will appear there if it's been deleted within the last 60 days. You can save the link to it locally, so you won't lose it after the 60 days have passed. When you go to the Answer you'll be able to see if only the Answer is gone, or if it was deleted as a result of deleting the entire Question.

Comment: Once you've found the link to the answer feel free to share it here so users can have a look and explain why it was deleted.

Comment: Thank you very much for your immediate, very helpful response! I was able to find my answer again. The associated question had been deleted. I now understand the "mechanisms" of stackoverflow much better.

Comment: As rene mentioned, you can share the link to the Answer in this meta post (if you want). Then users over 10,000 reputation points can perhaps help you understand why the Question was deleted, since they can see every post, deleted or not. If the Question isn't fit for Stack Overflow it's not uncommon that other users delete them. It could also have been deleted by post author or by [Community♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community), which deletes post that are considered abandoned and/or closed.